# Split fragments into separate modules

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-module

I have an activity with `BottomNavigationView` and 2 fragments that change based on that bottom buttons. (The same situation will be with the drawer setup or ViewPager or any other fragment-based approach)

How do I extract the fragments into separate feature modules?

The problem that I face is that my main activity, than contains the BottomNavigationView, needs to know about the fragments to instanciate them.

Answer (score 0):

For instant apps you need to have an addressable Activity to download and launch a new feature module. On the other hand you could use dynamic feature modules and instantiate the Fragment via reflection after it's hosting module has been downloaded via the PlayCore API.